# Unable to get the value of dynamic form elements in php which are generated using Java Script

Tags: php, javascript, forms, dynamic

plz dont mind me , i am new with javascript. I created an html form in a php file in which elements like radio buttons and check boxs and jump menus are generated and given values based on the on click function in javascript. The form elements with their respective values are appearing just fine but i am unable to retrieve that value of a dynamic form element via php. Any sort of help would be really appreciated ,have been stuck on this problem for quite sometime now, couldnt find an actual answer to the problem.
The Code is as follow:

```
     function addInput(divName) {

             var text=document.forms["newQuest"]["roptionName"].value;
             var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
             newdiv.innerHTML = text +  " <br><input type='radio' name='myInputs[]'>";
             document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);


            var form_data = {
                action:"add_rad",
                val:text
            };
            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "../scripts/addQuestion.php",
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(result) 
                    {
                        alert(result);
                        //document.getElementById("subjects").innerHTML=result;

                    }
                });
     }
```

In the addQuestion.php:
$array=$_GET['form_data'];

I always get the error regarding the undefined index in the above statement.

Answer (score 0):

to send the form data trough ajax, you have to serialize it and add it to your ajax request. Something like this:

```
formData = $('form').serialize();
```

If you want to add additonal data to it, you should be able to append it like so:

```
formdata.action = "add_rad";
...
```

The rest of your ajax call seems to be ok

On the server side you get the variables from the request like this:

```
$myInputs = $_REQUEST['myInputs'];
```

You should however make sure the data is there with something like array_key_exists or something, this is just a quick example...